# JCommandButton in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I design in `JFrame` window, and to drag the `JCommand` Button.

Then I change the command button name. And I display some text like ("image") in `JCommand` button. Then I add one image in `JCommand` button to display.

My problem is when I add image in command button the text disappears. Only image will display.

How to change `Jcommand` button display? It means inside of this command button the image will display up, the name will display under the image in command button?

How to do this?

Comment: What is a `Jcommand`, a `JCommand` or a `JCommandButton`?  DYM **`JButton`**?

Comment: what do you mean by "design _in_ JFrame" and "_drag_ the JCommand"? If your question is by any chance about _using_ a visual Gui builder or a non-core component, please add those facts to your description and/or tags

Comment: +1 for saying thankx to all. Regards

Answer (score 3):

```
  button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
  button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
JButton imageTextButton;

imageTextButton = new JButton(
                      "Click me to disable the next button"
                                        , new ImageIcon(imagePath));
imageTextButton.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
imageTextButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
```

This will display image like this [image: ButtonWithText]

Hope that might help.

Regards